# How can I keep members of a struct together with bubble sort?

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I've created a list of names in a .csv file, and I am trying to sort them alphabetically. Right now I've got an array of structs. The struct only has 2 members, the first and last name. I've got my bubble sort to sort based on first name which is what I want, but how can I keep the last name with them? When I print the array back out the last names do not line up with the first name.

```
void bubbleSort(cred name[], int n) { 

  char temp[25];
  int i,j;

  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<=n-i;j++)
      if(strcmp(name[j].first,name[j+1].first)>0)
      { 
        strcpy(temp,name[j].first);
        strcpy(name[j].first,name[j+1].first);
        strcpy(name[j+1].first,temp);
      }

   printf("The strings appears after sorting :\n");
   for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
     printf("%s  %s\n",name[i].first,name[i].last);
}
```

Comment: how is the struct defined? `typedef struct {char first[fixedN], last[fixedM];} cred;`? or using pointers?... if they are fixed you can directly swap the whole struct. ... otherwise you can swap just pointers without copying the strings.

Comment: OT: Be careful about using `<=` in your for loops. We would normally expect `n` to be the number of elements.

Comment: Uugh..... Don't swap names -- sort the array in the order you want. That is the purpose of a `struct`, to coordinate various pieces of otherwise unrelated information. Just `if(strcmp(name[j].first,name[j+1].first)>0) { cred tmp = name[j]; name[j] = name[j + 1]; name [j + 1] = tmp; }`

Answer (score 3):

I think your logic appears sound, someone is free to correct me, but you should also swap your last names whenever you swap the first names.

You could also just create a temp of type cred swap the previous element of the array with the next, both of type cred.

Comment: For future reference, it is often helpful to provide an example for new programmers to follow (especially those who are visually oriented and may have difficultly with reading interpretation, e.g. language barrier, etc..) Good answer otherwise.

Comment: Good idea. I'm new to responding, so I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Sure, best advice I can give is to just remember when responding, you step into the role of the teacher. Think about, if the roles were reversed, what you would want explained to you in order to develop a full understanding of why what you are doing is wrong and what you need to do to fix it. There is no hard-and-fast recipe for how much, or how little, to give, just use your best judgment about where the questioner is with his learning (based on the question) and help him gain a firm understanding of the solution. (you already got my vote, so there is nothing more I can do `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace

```
    strcpy(temp,name[j].first);
    strcpy(name[j].first,name[j+1].first);
    strcpy(name[j+1].first,temp);
```

with

```
    cred t = name[j];
    name[j] = name[j+1];
    name[j+1] = t;
```

as structs can be assigned to each other there is no need for copying member by member.

Also notice that all your `for` loops uses `<=` - like:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         ^^
         here
```

That seems to be a mistake as `n` probably represents the number of elements in the array. So your code is indexing out of bounds.

So change all your `for`loops to use `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: For some reason when using this algorithm or any like it that have been suggested it misses 0 index's "first" member